# How can I compare two Chinese strings in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt

Just started learning Qt.

Error when judging that these two Chinese strings are equal.

```
if(ui->name->text()!=userDatabase[i].name) 
// The former is Qlinetext data, and the latter is QString
{
    qDebug() <<( ui->name->text());
    QMessageBox::information(NULL,"Error","姓名不匹配，请重试");
}
```

Is it a different encoding method? How should I modify it? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I don't know about Qt's string types but many equivalent Chinese sentences can be represented differently in memory. Does Qt provide a locale-aware comparison function? Doing a simple binary comparison, even if it's the same encoding, isn't guaranteed to be accurate for Chinese.

Comment: Please print the actual values that you'd expect to compare equally, but don't. Use `myString.toUtf8().toHex()` to get it in unambiguous UTF-8 encoding, then edit it into your question.

Comment: Did you try https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#localeAwareCompare?

Comment: I have fixed this problem by adding QStringLiteral like this:QStringLiteral("吴女士"), although didn't know why..Still thanks a lot to all you above